# Not installing 'ds4drv'

Tags: software-installation, python

I'm running Ubuntu 15.10.

I've followed everything in this guide
[How to setup Dual Shock 4 controller with Ubuntu 13.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/427311/how-to-setup-dual-shock-4-controller-with-ubuntu-13-10)

But when I do the

```
sudo pip install ds4drv
```

I get this error

```
evdev/input.c:10:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

compilation terminated.

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-tOdKBQ/evdev/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-vQVfkA-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-tOdKBQ/evdev
Storing debug log for failure in /home/charlie/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: The solution would sem to be installing python-dev<br> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 0):

The Solution would seem to be, to install pyton-dev or a similar package:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530577/fatal-error-python-h-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.