# Installing and ds4drv emulator and python?

Tags: python, games, emulation

I've been trying to set up ds4drv and have problems understanding what to do with the files after extraction, (if if I'm supposed to extract at all). I'm aware I may have to download python as well.

Would someone kindly walk me through step by step?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please review http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask to get an idea how our Q & A site works and how you can best [edit] your post to help us help you!

Comment: You already have python installed (please don't mess with it!) You may need some additional python packages but installing them will be trivial :) Please [edit] your question to add what you have done so far and link to the instructions you are trying to follow. For example, what problems do you have following [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/427311/how-to-setup-dual-shock-4-controller-with-ubuntu-13-10/450091)?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've downloaded it from the [GitHub project](https://github.com/chrippa/ds4drv). If not, doesn't matter. We can use the recommended install method, straight from that page:

> ### Stable release
>
> Installing the latest release is simple by using pip:
>
> ```
> $ sudo pip install ds4drv
> ```

Now, before we can do this, we need to set up some things. Fortunately, this is easy. Just run all of the below commands to install the prerequisite packages and binaries (`pip`):

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools python-dev build-essential
sudo easy_install pip
```

Once you're done, run the commands specified on the GitHub page. You will be able to launch DS4DRV from the command line by just running `ds4drv`.

Comment: Uhm, why not simply `sudo apt-get install python-pip`? Is it really necessary do build it from source (even via easy-install)? Otherwise +1.